# Obtener datos de API a variables

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando pasar los datos de una API a variables.
Esta es la variable que obtengo por fetch:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que quiero es obtener coord1=-33.447964 y coord2=-70.658411

```
            let data = [];
            async function getCoords(){
              // gets the response from the api and put it inside a constant
              const response = await fetch("http://localhost/ejemplo/src/routes/clientes.php/api/clientes/id");
              //the response have to be converted to json type file, so it can be used
              const data = await response.json();
              //the addData adds the object "data" to an array
              addData(data)
            }

            function addData(object) {
              // the push method add a new item to an array
              // here it will be adding the object from the function getRandomUser each time it is called
              data.push(object);
              //the fetched data is available only on this scope
              console.log(data)
            }
            //Calls the function that fetches the data
            getCoords()
            console.log(data);
            var coord1;
            var coord2;
```

Comment: Puedes colocar en tu pregunta el array javascript? para ayudarte mejor

Comment: por lo que veo es var coord1=data[0][0]["lat"]; y coord2=data[0][0]["lag"]; prueba a ver así

Comment: Me aparece este error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: Quita un [0] y prueba, si nada edita tu pregunta con el array javascript para realizar prueba y poderte ayudar mejor

Comment: getCoords() es asincrónica, por tanto, solo podrás acceder a data dentro de alguna de las dos funciones. El console log y la declaración de variables van a ejecutarse antes de que se haga la llamada a la api.

Comment: Entonces para que funcione getCoords() no tiene que ser asincronica?

Comment: Hola, siempre recomiendo utilizar ` $.getJSON` por temas de comodidad a menos que la logica y algoritmo de la aplicacion requiera la funcion tipo `async`

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]

Comment: en que momento asignas los valores del api a `coord1`?? algo asi te hace falta `var coord1 = data[0][0]['lat'];`  y `var coord2 = data[0][0]['lag']; ` inténtalo y me avisas...

Comment: creo que tambien se puede con: `var coord1 = data[0][0]->lat;`  y `var coord2 = data[0][0]->lag;`